# How to efficiently use particle systems for large objects efficiently

Tags: particles, hair

I have a carpet texture that I have made:

[image]

But I would like to apply that texture to large objects:

[image]

Already, I can tell I will have scaling issues where if I were to directly apply the 'small' texture to the large object, I will be having a lot of gaps in the large texture. I would like to keep my detail if possible. The first thing that comes to mind is to just add more particles to the large object, but that would make Blender extremely slow.

What solutions should I employ here? I heard particle instancing might help?

I have attached the blend file for usage:

[image]